# loading resources from network in libGDX

Tags: libgdx

I have multiple self-written components of Actor type in my app. The application is multiplayer, so those actors have listeners which are notified by a separate thread when new information has arrived. The problem is the following - when I change the screens with `setScreen()` method of the `Game` class, the screen is loaded, but the information has not been received from the network yet, and there is a lag, after which the screen info is updated and the player sees relevant information. How can I stop the showing of the screen, until all the required information has been received from the network?

PS. I tried to do that through `while`-loop in `show` method, but to no avail (similar to update method of `AssetManager`). How is that usually done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop calling `setScreen()` when you don't have your display information. Whatever thread or event processor handles receiving the information should create a new `Runnable` that calls `setScreen` and send it to `Application.postRunnable()` so it'll run right before the next render.

Are you updating your actors in your networking thread? I'm not sure if that is safe.

Comment: Yes, they are updated in the networking thread. It seams safe as long as it does not draw anything. Thank you for the advice I will try it.